# PHP output array

Tags: php

despite hours of googling and reading various books I can't seem to output what I'm aiming for in the PHP program I'm trying to create (I'm new to this!). Basically, to start off with I just wanted to create a simple array and try to output my favourite football teams and their position or facts about them before I got into anything too complicated (unforunately even this has been somehwat difficult!). This is what I've got thus far:

```
<?php
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Football teams</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php


    $numbers = array("one", "two", "three", "four");

    $counter = 0;
    do {
        if($counter > 0) {
            $verse = true;
        }
        echo "$numbers[$counter] " ;
        if ($verse) {
            echo "Team " ;
        }
        else {
            echo "Teams" ;
        }
        print "are the best teams in the world <br/>" ;
        $counter++;
    } while($counter < 4);
    $football = $counter;
    while($football) {
        echo "$numbers[$football] men, " ;
        if ($verse) {
            echo "n<br/>" ;
        }
        echo "and rarely lose any games\n\n<br/><br/>" ; 
        $football--;
    }
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now that works without any errors, but it is all over the place and not in the correct order, so I'd appreciate any assistance. Can't see what's wrong myself when there are no errors, so I suspect there is a problem with one of the loops.

Thank you.

I expect to get:

```
one team are the best team in the world
and rarely lose any games

two teams are the best team in the world
two teams
and rarely lose any games

three teams are the best team in the world
three teams
and rarely lose any games

four teams are the best team in the world
four teams
and rarely lose any games
```

etc.

But what I'm getting is:

```
one team are the best team in the world
two teams are the best team in the world
three teams are the best team in the world
four teams are the best team in the world
```

UPDATE:

```
$counter = 0;
do {
if($counter > 0) {  
$verse = true;     
    }
echo "$numbers[$counter] " ;
if ($verse) {`
       echo "team " ; 
    }
    else {
        echo "teams " ;
    }
    print "are the best teams in the world<br/>" ;
    $football = $counter;
    while($football) {
    echo "$numbers[$football] teams, " ;
    if ($verse) {
        echo "<br/>" ;
    }
    echo "and rarely lose any games\n\n<br/><br/>" ; 
    $mower--;
}
$counter++;
} while($counter < 10);
?></body>
</html>
```

Using this code I've almost accomplished my aim, this is the output I get:

```
one team are the best team in the world,
two teams are the best team in the world,
two teams,
and rarely lose any games

three teams are the best team in the world,
three teams,
and rarely lose any games

two teams,
and they rarely lose any games,

four teams are the best team in the world,
four teams,
and they rarely lose any games,
```

**BUT, WHAT I WANT IS THIS:**

```
 one team are the best team in the world,
 and they rarely lose any games,

two teams are the best team in the world,
two teams,
and they rarely lose any games,

three teams are the best team in the world,
three teams, two teams,
and they rarely lose any games,

four teams are the best team in the world,
four teams, three teams, two teams,
and they rarely lose any game,
```

Thanks if anyone can help!!

Comment: Indent your code damnit!!

Comment: I thought I did, not sure what happened. Should I delete and repost?

Comment: should be indented now, please check

Comment: no just edit.. no big deal really, it just helps

Comment: why don't you edit you post and describe what you're getting and what you expect to get

Comment: Hopefully that's a bit clearer

Comment: Updated question with final edit

Answer (score 2):

Yes dear you are right. you are just exiting the loop early.

```
<?php
$numbers = array("one", "two", "three", "four");
$counter = 0;
$verse = false;
do {
        if($counter > 0) {
            $verse = true;
        }
        echo "$numbers[$counter] " ;
        if (!$verse) {
            echo "Team " ;
        }
        else {
            echo "Teams" ;
        }
        print "are the best teams in the world <br/>" ;
        $football = $counter;
        if($football > 0){
           while($football > 0){
            echo "$numbers[$football] Teams, " ;
            $football--;
           }
        }
        if ($verse) {
            echo "<br/>" ;
        }
        echo "and rarely lose any games\n\n<br/><br/>" ; 
        $football--;
    $counter++;
} while($counter < 4);    
?>
```

However this is not the best way to code this thing

Comment: Thank you! This is very very close but not still not quite :( I'm getting: one team are the best teams in the world
two teams are the best in the world
and rarely lose any games

Comment: I have edited my code....please check now

Comment: Ah! That is SO close. The only thing it isn't doing is what I've put in the final update of my question if you'll please have a look! In each new verse it should be updating in the middle - for example atm it says "three teams" but it should say "three teams, two teams"

Comment: allright...edited again...

Answer (score 0):

You missed a dollar sign in an array:

```
echo "$numbers[football] men, " ;
```

should be

```
echo "$numbers[$football] men, " ;
```

It's bad practice though to include arrays in strings this way as it's easy to make mistakes.  This would be better as

```
echo $numbers[$football] . " men, " ;
```

Another problem is that when the first loop ends `$counter` will be 4 which is higher than any of the indexes of the `$numbers` array.  In the next loop you attempt to access `$numbers[4]` which produces what is called an out of bounds error.  Instead the `$football--` should be at the beginning of the second loop, not the end.  Now the first iteration, $football will get set to 3, then `$numbers[3]` will be accessed and in the final iteration 1 will get turned into 0 and `$numbers[0]` will be accessed.  After that `while($football)` is no longer true and the loop exits.

Comment: That was just a typo, my problem is I think that the loop is indeed exiting early...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for seams to be how to loop trough an array and output things from it. Do it like this:

```
$myArray = array( 'element1', 'element2', ... );

foreach ( $myArray as $element )
{
    echo $myelement;
}
```

If you have some more complicated structure, like you said, facts about footballteams you can do this:

```
$teams = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Team1',
        'fact1' => 'fact1',
        ... etc ...
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Team1',
        'fact1' => 'fact1',
        ... etc ...
    ),
    ... etc ...
);

foreach ( $teams as $team )
{
    echo "Teamname: {$team['name']}";
    echo "Fact1: {$team['fact1']}";
    ... etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = array("one", "two", "three", "four");

$numbersrev = array_reverse($numbers);

foreach ($numbers as $numbersIten) 
{
    echo "Team " . $numbersIten . ' are the best teams in the world<br/>';
}
foreach ($numbersrev as $numbersrevIten) 
{
    echo '<br/>'.$numbersrevIten . ' men, <br/> and rarely lose any games <br/>';
}
```

Comment: Ensure you format code in the future.. and maybe add some detail about your answer.